# How do I write a SELECT statement with AND and OR conditions and AND Group conditions?

Tags: sql

I need to select the count of the following in a table using one SELECT statement:

1. (filler4 IN (6,7,8,9) AND address1 <> '5+')
2. filler4 < 6
3. filler4 <> 10
4. address1 <> '4x'
5. status in ('NC','A','B','N','UN')

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

This did not return the correct results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Counts FROM [server].[database].[schema].table
WHERE ( filler4 IN(6,7,8,9) AND address1 != '5+' )
  AND status in ('NC','A','B','N','UN')
  OR filler4 != 10 
  OR filler4 < 6  
  OR address1 !='4x'
```

The results are not returning the correct number of records.  I expect it to be 208,787 but I am getting 313,556.

Comment: share sample data and its output

Comment: >AND status in ('NC','A','B','N','UN')
shouldn't that be "OR"?
Also, it's not clear what exactly do you want to select with your query. Do you want rows that match any of the conditions or all conditions?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what logic you really want.  I suspect it is more like this:

```
((filler4 IN (6, 7, 8, 9) AND address1 <> '5+') OR
 (filler4 < 6 AND filler4 <> 10)
) AND
address1 <> '4x' ND
status in ('NC', 'A', 'B', 'N', 'UN')
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the question, you want to count rows group by conditions mentioned in points 1,2,3, etc.

MySQL query would be like this ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Counts FROM table
group by (filler4 IN(6,7,8,9) AND address1 != '5+' ), 
         status in ('NC','A','B','N','UN'), 
         filler4 != 10, 
         filler4 < 6, 
         address1 != '4x'
```